# AES-GCM needs the same init_vector from encryption FOR decryption. Why?

Tags: javascript, typescript, encryption

I've created a TypeScript example [from MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/deriveKey) as verbatim as I could to illustrate. It encrypts and decrypts just fine. I just noticed that, for Decryption to work, it requires the same `init_vector` from encryption. Isn't the `init_vector` supposed to be a nonce?

How is the person receiving the message going to know what the `init_vector` I've used for **encryption** if **decryption** is a separate process done at a different place and time?

```
const message_plain: string = "Hello World!";
const password_plain: string = "letmein";

// AES-GCM - ENCRYPTION

const pbkdf2_salt: Uint8Array = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(16)); // 128 bits
const pbkdf2_iterations: number = 100000;
const init_vector: Uint8Array = crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(12)); // 96 bits

const utf8_encoder: TextEncoder = new TextEncoder();

const message_bytes: Uint8Array = utf8_encoder.encode(message_plain);
const password_bytes: Uint8Array = utf8_encoder.encode(password_plain);

const crypto_key_material: CryptoKey = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
  "raw",
  password_bytes,
  { name: "PBKDF2" },
  false,
  ["deriveBits", "deriveKey"],
);
const crypto_key_derived: CryptoKey = await crypto.subtle.deriveKey(
  {
    "name": "PBKDF2",
    salt: pbkdf2_salt,
    "iterations": pbkdf2_iterations,
    "hash": "SHA-256",
  },
  crypto_key_material,
  { "name": "AES-GCM", "length": 256 },
  true,
  ["encrypt", "decrypt"],
);

const message_encrypted: ArrayBuffer = await crypto.subtle.encrypt(
  { name: "AES-GCM", iv: init_vector },
  crypto_key_derived,
  message_bytes,
);
const message_encrypted_bytes: Uint8Array = new Uint8Array(message_encrypted);

console.log(
  `[${message_encrypted.byteLength} bytes total] -> ${message_encrypted_bytes}`,
);

// AES-GCM - DECRYPTION

const utf8Decoder: TextDecoder = new TextDecoder();

try {
  const message_decrypted: ArrayBuffer = await crypto.subtle.decrypt(
    { name: "AES-GCM", iv: init_vector },
    crypto_key_derived,
    message_encrypted,
  );
  const message_decrypted_bytes: Uint8Array = new Uint8Array(message_decrypted);

  console.log(utf8Decoder.decode(message_decrypted_bytes));
} catch (e) {
  console.log("*** Decryption error ***");
}
```

Comment: For any given key, you _must_ use a _different_ IV for each encryption. (If you use the same key/IV pair each time you'll end up XORing the same bitstream into your different plaintexts. Your ciphertexts could then be XORed with each other to reveal similar and different bits.) There are various ways to use a different IV for each encryption. Sometimes the IV is derived from, say, the message sequence number. Another approach is generate a random IV and send it with the ciphertext.

Comment: This link [AES-GCM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/decrypt#aes-gcm) states that iv must match the value that was used for encryption. Which then means, for every message I encrypt, the iv for that message must also be sent to destination.

Comment: Yes, for every message you need to send the IV or make it predictable (though predictably different each time).

Comment: For GCM the repetition of key/IV pairs is a fatal bug ([here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/26790)). For a *fixed* key, this is usually avoided with a *random* nonce/IV. Since the nonce/IV is *not secret*, it is typically concatenated at byte level (IV|ciphertext) and separated from the decrypting side based on its known length.

Comment: The same applies to the salt: randomly generate, concatenate (salt|IV|ciphertext), separate. Note that in WebCrypto (and in many other libraries) the ciphertext is already a concatenation, namely of the *actual* ciphertext and the GCM tag: ciphertext = actualCiphertext|gcmTag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use asymmetric encryption like RSA which has a public / private key, for example this [node-rsa](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rsa) package.

In terms of having the same initial vector, I found this snippet taken from this [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3965/what-is-the-main-difference-between-a-key-an-iv-and-a-nonce):

> In any case, the IV never needs to be kept secret — if it did, it would be a key, not an IV. Indeed, in most cases, keeping the IV secret would not be practical even if you wanted to since the recipient needs to know it in order to decrypt the data (or verify the hash, etc.).

Comment: Feels like I should be looking at a different type of encryption for this use case.

Comment: @suchislife maybe asymmetric encryption which makes use of a public and private key like RSA?

Comment: Now you're talking. I was just thinking that. Right tool for the job. Since you've inspired the conclusion feel free to update the answer to RSA so I can accept without getting destroyed.

Comment: @suchislife sweet just updated the post!

Comment: But how do you deal with the size restriction of the plaintext in RSA? What if you want to send a message longer than the key size? At the other extreme, if the messages are short, do you really want to be padding them all out to the key size?

Comment: @RichardHeap sounds like this user needs an asymmetric solution, I would be tempted to say why not use RSA to share the IV, what’s your take?

Comment: I do not see the need for asymmetric encryption here. IV and salt are randomly generated, both are not secret and are therefore usually concatenated with the ciphertext at byte level (and separated on the receiver side). That's it. Asymmetric ciphers are slow and can only encrypt a short plaintext. They are typically used for key exchange/agreement in hybrid encryption (e.g. RSA + AES).

Comment: @Topaco interesting, I was originally just sharing about OPs question about IV being secret. Train of thought sounds like he wanted asymmetric, hard to be certain without more context, what’s your thoughts?

Comment: Switching to asymmetric encryption based on the false assumption that the IV is secret is the wrong way to go. Whether there are valid reasons to switch to asymmteric encryption? My guess is no, but that can't be definitively decided based on the info posted. For that, the OP would have to describe his use case in more detail.

Comment: @Topaco makes sense, seemed like OP wanted a system where very little was shared, wasn’t sure what he meant by that, should I update the answer?

Comment: In the first place, I would describe in the answer the correct handling of IV/nonce in the context of GCM and the correct handling of the salt (especially that both are not secret, since this seems to have been the source of the confusion). But that is entirely up to you.

Comment: Well, I could use CBC which does not require iv for decryption although it's less secure according to the Internet.

Comment: @suchislife - CBC also needs an IV. Possibly you mean ECB. ECB does not use an IV and is therefore *insecure*. It's hard to understand why you want to switch from the secure GCM (i.e. authenticated encryption) to the less secure CBC or worse the insecure ECB.

Comment: CBC does not require the same IV for DECRYPTION.

Comment: @suchislife - If with CBC the wrong IV is used during decryption, then the first block of the resulting plaintext is corrupted. You can easily check this in the [CBC flowchart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_block_chaining_(CBC)). If your implementation works without an IV, you either don't use CBC or a static IV is silently applied (for encryption and decryption e.g. a zero IV), which is insecure.

Comment: It appears I still have much to learn. Thank you.